# Two overlapping images via CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to enable a user to drag an image (e.g. a face) on another image (e.g. a map square). I implemented the drag&drop with an Angular directive and it kinda work. What is not working is the position of the dropped image (the face): it is not overlaying, but it is being placed below the map square.

The starting HTML code is generated via ng-repeat, but the resulting element is this:

```
<span style="display: inline-block;position:relative;">
      <img src="map_square.jpg" class="map-image">
</span>
```

When dropping, it becomes:

```
<span style="display: inline-block">
      <img src="map_square.jpg" class="map-image">
      <img src="face.jpg" class="face-image-on-map">
</span>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
.map-image {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 42px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.face-image-on-map {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 42px;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: .8;
}
```

As a result of this, I would expect the face image to be over the map square, both being inside the span-delimited area (42*42px).
Instead, the face image is outside the span area, below the map square (actually, it is over another map square image, i.e. the one below the actual target).

Changing position of the face causes the face image to be placed on the right of the target (far away from it).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try switching the position:absolute and position:relative.

Comment: That's not an option: changing the position of the map square causes changes globally (i.e. all map squares become overlapped in a single position)

Comment: A question to the class names: Both `img` tags have the same class, so `.face-image-on-map` is unused in your example. Is this right?

Comment: @TuringTux thanks, I corrected my OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing the `top` and the `left` property in `.face-image-on-map`.

So I would recommend this:

```
.face-image-on-map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; /* Positoning: distance from top border */
  left: 0; /* Positioning: distance from left border */
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 42px;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: .8;
}
```

(See the [W3Schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) for more information)

Hope this is want you wanted :)

Comment: Correct! I was playing around and just couldn't figure that out. Actually, I also need position:relative on the containing span element. I added it to the OP.

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad I could help you. I'll add a link to the W3Schools page, just in case someone needs that later.